# Getting available fonts list returns warning on iOS App

Tags: ios, swift, fonts

I was getting available fonts with following code but I am getting this

**CoreText note: Client requested name ".SFUI-Regular", it will get TimesNewRomanPSMT rather than the intended font. All system UI font access should be through proper APIs such as CTFontCreateUIFontForLanguage() or +[UIFont systemFontOfSize:].**

warning many times at log recently for this line of code

**let fontNames = UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: names)**

Is there a neat way of getting rid of this.

As in warning said we are getting the same font name into the list for repeated warnings.

I filter out repeated font names later but there must be better way doing it.

```
    var list:[String] = []
    let familyNames = UIFont.familyNames
    
    // family names
    for names in familyNames {
        
        
        let fontNames = UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: names)
        
        // loads font names at each family fontList.count gives exact font number count
        for k in 0 ..< fontNames.count {

            list.append(fontNames[k])
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hmm, I copied your code to Playground and it runs without a warning.

Comment: I also copied your code, not showing any warning

Comment: Which iOS version are you running this in?

Comment: I was testing on iOS 15.1